# MvvmCross UWP - How to use MvxInteraction

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross with my UWP application.

I just want to show the custom content dialog to get user input on executing a command.

I have created a  ContentDialog with TextBox to get the data. But How can I call the Dialog from ViewModel? I went through the MvxInteraction class, but I didn't get any idea to how to bind this interaction with View and ViewModel.

Comment: "But How can I call the Dialog from ViewModel?" Could I know what does this mean? Could you please detail that? And could you please upload some relative code snippet?